# Generate List of Towns using GoogleV3

Tags: python, python-3.x, geocoding, google-geocoder

I'm trying to generate a list of towns in Malta together with their Latitute/Longitude coordinates using Google's Geocoder (GoogleV3) with geopy. [The reason I am doing this is because I couldn't find such a list in the first place - if anyone knows of one, please let me know!]

I created the file `towns.txt` containing the list of places in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180911203230/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_in_Malta), and I'm running the following code to generate the output:

```py
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

# Load wikipedia list of cities/towns.
towns = open("towns.txt", "r").read().splitlines()

# Prepare to write to file (JSON format)
out = open("output.txt", "w")
out.write("[{\n")

# Use Google API to find Latitude/Longitude for each town
geocoder = GoogleV3(api_key="mYaPiKeYhErE")
for town in towns:
    town_object = geocoder.geocode(town)
    if town_object:
        town_string = '    "Town" : "' +  town + '",\n' \
                      + '    "Latitude" : "' + str(town_object.latitude) + '",\n' \
                      + '    "Longitude" : "' + str(town_object.longitude) + '",\n' \
                      + '    "GoogleAddress" : "' + town_object.address + '"\n' \
                      + ('}, {\n' if town != towns[-1] else '}]')
        print(town, "(Google found: "+town_object.address+")", town_object.latitude, town_object.longitude)
        out.write(town_string)

# Close file
out.close()
```

This produces the desired output, showing the towns in the console as the file is generated. The only issue is that after a while, I get errors such as

```
geopy.exc.GeocoderUnavailable: Service not available
```

or

```
geopy.exc.GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out
```

I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to resolve this (I'm using a free trial of the Google API, maybe that's why?)

---

**ADDENDUM: `towns.txt`**

For completeness, here is the file I am reading from. I used some vim trickery to get all the names in a somewhat consistent format.

```
Il-Belt Valletta, Malta
L-Imdina, Malta
Il-Birgu, Malta
L-Isla, Malta
Bormla, Malta
Ħal Qormi, Malta
Ħaż-Żebbuġ, Malta
Ħaż-Żabbar, Malta
Is-Siġġiewi, Malta
Iż-Żejtun, Malta
Ħ'Attard, Malta
Ħal Balzan, Malta
Birkirkara, Malta
Birżebbuġa, Malta
Ħad-Dingli, Malta
Il-Fgura, Malta
Il-Furjana, Malta
Il-Gudja, Malta
Il-Gżira, Malta
Ħal Għargħur, Malta
Ħal Għaxaq, Malta
Il-Ħamrun, Malta
L-Iklin, Malta
Il-Kalkara, Malta
Ħal Kirkop, Malta
Ħal Lija, Malta
Ħal Luqa, Malta
Il-Marsa, Malta
Marsaskala, Malta
Marsaxlokk, Malta
Il-Mellieħa, Malta
L-Imġarr, Malta
Il-Mosta, Malta
L-Imqabba, Malta
L-Imsida, Malta
In-Naxxar, Malta
Raħal Ġdid, Malta
Pembroke, Malta
Tal-Pietà, Malta
Il-Qrendi, Malta
Ir-Rabat, Malta
Ħal Safi, Malta
San Ġiljan, Malta
San Ġwann, Malta
San Pawl il-Bahar, Malta
Santa Luċija, Malta
Santa Venera, Malta
Tas-Sliema, Malta
Is-Swieqi, Malta
Ta' Xbiex, Malta
Ħal Tarxien, Malta
Ix-Xgħajra, Malta
Iż-Żurrieq, Malta
L-Imtarfa, Malta
Baħar iċ-Ċagħaq, Malta
Baħrija, Malta
Bubaqra, Malta
Burmarrad, Malta
Fleur de Lys, Malta
Gwardamanġa, Malta
Ħal Farruġ, Malta
Madliena, Malta
Paceville, Malta
Kappara, Malta
San Pietru, Żabbar, Malta
Swatar, Malta
Tal-Virtù, Rabat, Malta
L-Abatija, Imġarr, Malta
Bulebel iż-Żgħir, Żabbar, Malta
Albert Town, Marsa, Malta
L-Armier, Mellieħa, Malta
Il-Ballut, Imġarr, Malta
Il-Balluta, San Ġiljan, Malta
Baqqari, Zurrieq, Malta
Belt-is-Sebħ, Floriana, Malta
Bengħajsa, Birżebbuġa, Malta
Il-Beżbiżija, Mosta, Malta
Il-Bidni, Marsaskala, Malta
Il-Bidnija, Malta
Bieb ir-Ruwa, Rabat, Malta
Binġemma, Imġarr, Malta
Birguma, Naxxar, Malta
Bir id-Deheb, Żejtun, Malta
Il-Blata l-Bajda, Ħamrun, Malta
Il-Bokka taċ-Ċarcara, Imġarr, Malta
Buġibba, San Pawl il-Baħar, Malta
Bulebel, Żejtun, Malta
Buqana, Rabat, Malta
Il-Buskett, Ħad-Dingli, Malta
Iċ-Ċanta, Rabat, Malta
Iċ-Ċens l-Iswed, Malta
Iċ-Ċirkewwa, Malta
Delimara, Malta
Id-Dwejra, Rabat, Malta
Faqqanija, Malta
Il-Fawwara, Siġġiewi, Malta
Fomm ir-Riħ, Imġarr, Malta
Fuq San Pawl, Bormla, Malta
Fuq Tal-Blat, Ħal Qormi, Malta
Ġebel Ciantar, Siġġiewi, Malta
Ġebel l-Abjad, Malta
Ġebel San Martin, Żejtun, Malta
Ġnejna Bay, Imġarr, Malta
Ġnien Borg, Malta
Ġnien Fieres, Malta
Ġnien San Pawl, Malta
Il-Girgenti, Siġġiewi, Malta
Il-Gwiedi, Malta
L-Għadira, Mellieħa, Malta
Għajn Astas, San Pawl il-Baħar, Malta
Għajn Dwieli, Malta
Għajn il-Kbira, Malta
Għajn Kajjet, Rabat, Malta
Għajn Klieb, Rabat, Malta
Għajn Tajba, Rabat, Malta
Għajn Tuffieħa, Malta
L-Għallis, Naxxar, Malta
L-Għemieri, Rabat, Malta
Għar ix-Xiħ, Malta
Għar Lapsi, Siġġiewi, Malta
Għar Żerriegħa, Malta
Ħaġar Qim, Qrendi, Malta
Ħal Dmikki, Ħal Għaxaq, Malta
Ħal Dragu, Burmarrad, Malta
Ħal Far, Malta
Ħal Tmiem, Żejtun, Malta
Ħas-Saptan, Ħal Għaxaq, Malta
Ħlantun, Malta
Il-Ħofra tar-Ritz, Malta
Il-Ħrieri, Żebbuġ, Malta
Il-Ħbula, Ħad-Dingli, Malta
Il-Ħfar, Malta
Il-Kalkara, Il-Baħrija, Malta
Il-Katakombi, Rabat, Malta
Il-Ponta, Malta
Kalafrana, Birżebbuġa, Malta
Kordin, Paola, Malta
Il-Kunċizzjoni, Rabat, Malta
L-Aħrax, Mellieha, Malta
L-Erba' Qaddisin, Ħal Qormi, Malta
Limbordin, San Pawl il-Baħar, Malta
Lippija, Imġarr, Malta
Il-Lunzjata, Rabat, Malta
Il-Magħtab, In-Naxxar, Malta
Il-Manikata, Il-Mellieħa, Malta
Manoel Island, Il-Gżira, Malta
Il-Marfa, Il-Mellieħa, Malta
Il-Marnisi, Birżebbuġa, Malta
L-Imġiebaħ, Il-Mellieħa, Malta
Misraħ Kola, Ħ'Attard, Malta
Il-Miżieb, Il-Mellieħa, Malta
L-Imrieħel, Birkirkara, Malta
L-Imselliet, L-Imġarr, Malta
L-Imtaħleb, Rabat, Malta
In-Nadur, Malta
In-Nigret, Iż-Żurrieq, Malta
Il-Pwales, San Pawl il-Baħar, Malta
Il-Qajjenza, Birżebbuġa, Malta
Il-Qattara, Malta
Il-Qawra, San Pawl il-Baħar, Malta
Qerd in-Naħal, Malta
Raba' Nemel, Rabat, Malta
Ras il-Wied, L-Imġarr, Malta
Ricasoli, Il-Kalkara, Malta
Is-Salina, In-Naxxar, Malta
San Ġwann t'Għuxa, Bormla, Malta
San Lawrenz tal-Għolja, Is-Siġġiewi, Malta
San Martin, San Pawl il-Baħar, Malta
San Niklaw, Il-Qrendi, Malta
San Pawl tat-Tarġa, In-Naxxar, Malta
Sant' Anton, Ħ'Attard, Malta
Santa Katerina, Rabat, Malta
Santa Margarita, Il-Mosta, Malta
Santa Marija Estate, Il-Mellieħa, Malta
Is-Santi, L-Imġarr, Malta
Is-Saqqajja, Rabat, Malta
Is-Sgħajtar, Il-Mosta, Malta
L-Iskrivit, L-Imġarr, Malta
Il-Bajja ta' San Ġorġ, San Ġiljan, Malta
Il-Bajja ta' San Tumas, Marsaskala, Malta
Ta' Barkat, Ix-Xgħajra, Malta
Ta' Brija, Is-Siġġiewi, Malta
Ta' Frajna, Malta
Ta' Ganza, Iż-Żejtun, Malta
Ta' Giorni, San Giljan, Malta
Ta' Ġawhar, Malta
Ta' Għadajma, Malta
Ta' Ħaramija, Malta
Ta' Ħemsija, Malta
Ta' Kandja, Is-Siġġiewi, Malta
Ta' Lampat, Malta
Ta' Landrijiet, Rabat, Malta
Ta' Lanza, Malta
Ta' Laurenti, Rabat, Malta
Ta' Loretu, Il-Gudja, Malta
Ta' Mlit, Il-Mosta, Malta
Ta' Mrejnu, L-Imġarr, Malta
Ta' Newma, Malta
Ta' Ngħajsa, Malta
Ta' Paris, Birkirkara, Malta
Ta' Pascarella, Ħal Qormi, Malta
Ta' Pennellu, Il-Mellieħa, Malta
Ta' Qali, Attard, Malta
Ta' Rbazza, Malta
Ta' Rużarju, Malta
Ta' Tewma, Mgarr, Malta
Ta' Xurraf, Malta
Ta' Żgamardi, Malta
Ta' Żokkrija, Mosta, Malta
Ta' Żwejt, San Gwann, Malta
Tal-Bebbux, Zurrieq, Malta
Tal-Blajjiet, Marsaskala, Malta
Tal-Boxxla, Malta
Tal-Bujjar, Marsaskala, Malta
Tal-Ferħa, Gharghur, Malta
Tal-Fuklar, Attard, Malta
Tal-Ibraġ, Swieqi, Malta
Tal-Għadir, Malta
Tal-Għaqba, Malta
Tal-Għolja, Siggiewi, Malta
Tal-Ħamri, Malta
Tal-Ħandaq, Qormi, Malta
Tal-Ħawli, Birgu, Malta
Tal-Kaccaturi, Malta
Tal-Kanuni, Malta
Tal-Karwija, Malta
Tal-Landier, Malta
Tal-Laqnija, Malta
Tal-Madliena Barra x-Xagħra, Malta
Tal-Markiż, Malta
Tal-Menħir Estate, Kirkop, Malta
Tal-Milord, Malta
Tal-Mirakli, Lija, Malta
Tal-Palma, Mgarr, Malta
Tal-Papa, Birzebbuga, Malta
Tal-Plier, Zabbar, Malta
Tal-Providenza, Siggiewi, Malta
Tal-Qattus, Birkirkara, Malta
Tal-Qroqq, Msida, Malta
Tal-Wata, Malta
Tar-Rabbat, Hamrun, Malta
Tar-Ramel, Malta
Tarġa Gap, Mosta, Malta
Tas-Salib, Malta
Tas-Salib tal-Għolja, Siggiewi, Malta
Tas-Salvatur, Malta
Tas-Sirena, Malta
Tat-Tabija, Malta
Tat-Tilliera, Malta
Upper Garden (Fuq il-Ġonna), Swieqi, Malta
Verdala, Bormla, Malta
Wardija, San Pawl il-Bahar, Malta
Wied Fulija, Zurrieq, Malta
Wied Gerżuma, Malta
Wied Ħazrun, Malta
Wied Ħesri, Malta
Wied il-Bużbież, Malta
Wied il-Kbir, Qormi, Malta
Wied il-Lunzjata, Victoria, Malta
Wied is-Sewda, Qormi, Malta
Wied iż-Żebbuġ, Malta
Wied iż-Żiju, Marsaskala, Malta
Wied iż-Żurrieq, Qrendi, Malta
Wied Rini, Rabat, Malta
Wied ta' Baqqiegħa, Malta
Wied ta' Ħal Mula, Haz-Zebbug, Malta
Wied ta' San Martin, Malta
Wied ta' Sant' Antnin, Malta
Wied tal-Blata, Malta
Wied tal-Ħandaq, Qormi, Malta
Wied tal-Isperanza, Mosta, Malta
Wied tal-Isqof, Rabat, Malta
Wied tal-Qlejgħa (Chadwick Lakes), Mosta, Malta
Wied tat-Troll, Malta
Wied Xkora, Malta
Xagħra Ħurija, Malta
Xagħra tal-Isqof, Rabat, Malta
Xemxija, San Pawl il-Bahar, Malta
Xifer il-Kief, Mgarr, Malta
Xrob l-Għagin, Marsaxlokk, Malta
Xwieki, Gharghur, Malta
Żebbiegħ, Mgarr, Malta
Żonqor, Marsaskala, Malta
Ir-Rabat, Gozo
Il-Fontana, Gozo
Għajnsielem, Gozo
L-Għarb, Gozo
L-Għasri, Gozo
Ta' Kerċem, Gozo
Il-Munxar, Gozo
In-Nadur, Gozo
Il-Qala, Gozo
San Lawrenz, Gozo
Ta' Sannat, Gozo
Ix-Xagħra, Gozo
Ix-Xewkija, Gozo
Iż-Żebbuġ, Gozo
Xlendi, Gozo
Ix-Xlendi, Gozo
Marsalforn, Gozo
Santa Luċija, Gozo
Birbuba, L-Għarb, Gozo
Borġ Għarib, Għajnsielem, Gozo
Iċ-Ċittadella, Victoria, Gozo
Daħlet Qorrot, Il-Qala, Gozo
Fort Chambray, Għajnsielem, Gozo
Għajn Ħosna, Ix-Xagħra, Gozo
Għajn Lukin, Ix-Xagħra, Gozo
Għar ix-Xiħ, Għajnsielem, Gozo
Ħondoq ir-Rummien, Il-Qala, Gozo
Id-Dwejra, San Lawrenz, Gozo
Il-Qbajjar, Marsalforn, Gozo
Il-Qortin, In-Nadur, Gozo
Ix-Xwejni, Marsalforn, Gozo
Kemmuna, Għajnsielem, Gozo
Kemmunett, Għajnsielem, Gozo
L-Imġarr, Għajnsielem, Gozo
Mġarr ix-Xini, Ta' Sannat, Gozo
Ir-Ramla l-Ħamra, Ix-Xagħra, Gozo
San Blas, In-Nadur, Gozo
Santu Pietru, L-Għarb, Gozo
Ta' Bin Ġemma, In-Nadur, Gozo
Ta' Ċenċ, Ta' Sannat, Gozo
Ta' Cordina, Għajnsielem, Gozo
Ta' Dbieġi, L-Għarb, Gozo
Ta' Għammar, L-Għasri, Gozo
Ta' Ħamet, Ix-Xagħra, Gozo
Ta' Kuxxina, In-Nadur, Gozo
Ta' Nazzarenu, Ix-Xagħra, Gozo
Ta' Pinu, L-Għarb, Gozo
Ta' Seguna, Ta' Sannat, Gozo
Ta' Xħajma, In-Nadur, Gozo
Taċ-Ċawla, Victoria, Malta, Gozo
Tal-Barmil, Ix-Xewkija, Gozo
Tal-Ħniena, Ix-Xewkija, Gozo
Tal-Ibraġ, Victoria, Gozo
Tal-Kaċċaturi, Ix-Xagħra, Gozo
Wied il-Għasri, L-Għasri, Gozo
Wied il-Lunzjata, Il-Fontana, Gozo
Wied il-Mielaħ, L-Għarb, Gozo
Wied tal-Blata, Il-Qala, Gozo
Xatt l-Aħmar, Għajnsielem, Gozo
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: add `timeout = None` to the `GoogleV3()` call:

```
geocoder = GoogleV3(api_key="mYaPiKeYhErE", timeout=None)
```

Source: [here](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues/199)